# Write information to the top of a file using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, javascript-build, gulp-insert

I've been slowly integrating gulp into my solution. I'm using cassette to manage dependencies, and now I have gulp running bower, copying minified files to my source directory where they are referenced (don't want to really break old references), and now I need to manually insert the appropriate cassette references to the top of each file using ///  and I can't figure out how to do it using Gulp. I know it would probably be easiest to use gulp-insert to do this and use the prepend function. I've also got an array of files and their dependencies to loop through. Pretty new to gulp here, so be gentle, and let me know if there are other ways I should be structuring this.

```
gulp.task('organizeDependencies', function() {
   for (var x = 0; x < dependencies.length; x++) {
       file(dependencies[x].file)
          .pipe(insert.prepend('/// <reference path="'+dependencies[x].dependency+'" />'));
   }
});
```

The dependency array looks like this:

```
var dependencies = [{
    'file': 'angular-resource.min.js',
    'dependency': 'angular.min.js',
},
{
    'file': 'angular-slick.min.js',
    'dependency': 'angular.min.js',
}];
```

I think I need to do something with Vinyl to pass the file into the stream, but that's still a little confusing to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out and will put the answer here for anyone else looking for the solution. The trick was that I wasn't fully qualifying the path to each file, and I needed to call src and dest to actually write the file to the right location.

```
gulp.task('organizeDependencies', function () {
for (var x = 0; x < dependencies.length; x++) {
    gulp.src('Scripts/Lib/' + dependencies[x].file)
        .pipe(insert.prepend('/// <reference path="' + dependencies[x].dependency + '" />\n'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Scripts/Lib/'));
}
```

});